# ¿Por qué no puedo usar más de un CommandButton? - Visual Basic - WORD-Office Professional Plus 2010

Tags: vb.net, vb, ms-word, visual-basic

Creé una plantilla Word habilitada para macros con varios Command Buttons.

Los Botones que creé sirven principalmente para insertar texto de diferentes documentos, y otros sirven para borrar los botones que no se han usado.

En la plantilla puedo haccer uso de todos los botones sin ningún problema.

Sin embargo, al crear un nuevo documento basado en la plantilla mencionada, **sólo puedo usar un botón (no importa cual) y los demás ya no reaccionan.**

Por default, al insertar cada botón se crea con "Private Sub", yo cambié todos a "Plubic Sub".

Espero puedan ayudarme :(

Comment: Habría que ver si la rutina de los botones _termina_ o no. O si estás en algún modo debug/design que no detiene la ejecución cuando termina la subrutina

Comment: Sí termina, bueno, les pongo "End Sub" a cada botón. No sé si deba modificar eso

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné...

Lo que pasa es que yo guardé como "Plantilla habilitada con macros". En cuanto hice una copia "**Documento** habilitado con macros" ya no hubo ningún problema y pude usar los botones normalmente.